# SQLite Column Error : table XXXX has no column named ZZZZ

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to insert rows in my Student Table which contains two rows : ID and Name

Here is the addHandler function which is implemented in MyDBHandler class :

```
 public void addHandler(Student student) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_ID, student.getID());
    values.put(COLUMN_NAME, student.getStudentName());
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    db.close();
}
```

The **onCreate** method is :-

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) { 
    String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ," + COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT )"; 
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE); 
}
```

The attributes of MyDBHandler class which extends SQLiteOpenHelper :

```
 private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "studentDB.db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Student";
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "StudentID";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "StudentName";
```

I have a ADD Button in my activity_main.xml file and here is the code behind :

```
public void add(View view){
    MyDBHandler dbHandler = new MyDBHandler(this, null, null, 1);
    int id = Integer.parseInt(studentIdText.getText().toString());
    String name = studentNameText.getText().toString();
    Student student = new Student(id, name);
    dbHandler.addHandler(student);
    studentIdText.setText("");
    studentNameText.setText("");
}
```

The app is running perfectly but when i want to insert a row in the table , i get the following errors in Run Tab :

```
E/SQLiteLog: (1) table Student has no column named StudentID
E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting StudentName=yassine StudentID=10

android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table Student has no column named StudentID (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO Student(StudentName,StudentID) VALUES (?,?)
#################################################################
Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)
Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.
    (table Student has no column named StudentID (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO Student(StudentName,StudentID) VALUES (?,?))
#################################################################
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1093)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:670)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:59)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1607)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1479)
    at com.example.test.MyDBHandler.addHandler(MyDBHandler.java:48)
    at com.example.test.MainActivity.add(MainActivity.java:40)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5246)
    at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10566)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21256)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6917)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

Any recommendations ?

Comment: My Bad ! won't do it again !

Comment: How did you create your table?

Comment: Hi i used the onCreate method

Comment: public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + 
    COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ," + COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT )";
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
        }

Comment: try uninstalling the App an rerunning as you may have changed the structure (e.g. added the StudentId column). **onCreate** only runs once when the database is created rather than every time the App is run, so changes made will not be applied unless you force **onCreate** to run.

Comment: How can i force it to run ?

Comment: You don't force as such, you uninstall the App, re-install and rerun (alternately you can delete the App's data).

Comment: Drop your studentDB.db database and rerun your program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is very likely a mis-conception in regard to the **onCreate** method. That is it **onCreate** doesn't run every time the App is run. **onCreate** will only run if the database doesn't actually exist. If the database has already been created by another previous run of the App then the **onCreate** method is not run.

As such any changes made to the structure of the database, as typically applied in the **onCreate** method will not be applied.

It would appear that you have added the defnition for the **StudentId** column, to the code in the **onCreate** method, after the App has been run.

As long as you have no data that needs to be preserved (which is very likely) then the simplest solution is to do 1 of the following :-

- delete or clear the App's data (via settings/Apps)
- uninstall the App

and then rerun the App, the database will then be created using the code as per the modified **onCreate** code.